# Why is the as appearing after the conversion?

Tags: node.js

I am rendering a React app on server, and there is an issue in one of my files. In my ES6 syntax I have:

`import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form';`

And after the conversion I get a syntax error `Unexpected identifier` pointing at the 'as':

```
var  reducer as formReducer = require("redux-form").reducer as formReducer;;
```

Server requires

```
require('babel-register')({ presets: ['es2015', 'react'] });
require('import-export');
require('babel-polyfill');
```

Comment: `var  reducer as formReducer = require("redux-form").reducer as formReducer;;` is not valid JavaScript. How exactly is that code generated? It seems like you are using a tool that doesn't implement ES6 `import`s correctly (i.e. it is not aware that imports can be renamed).

Comment: I updated my question to include my requires at the top of my server file

Comment: there must be something else wrong, babel doesn't produce that error.

Comment: Any idea what it could be or what I should look for? I'm lost on where to look for the error. Maybe this is the error? `at Object.Module._extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/name/Documents/react/node_modules/node-hook/index.js:73:14)`

Comment: I assume the `import-export` module is the culprit. You don't need it if you are using `babel-register`.

Comment: Ok that solves the issue, but I still get another syntax error in my reducer file. `>  8 |  return { ...state, isShowing: true };` `Unexpected token` pointing at the `...`. I thought babel-register would solve this issue.

Comment: @joethemow: You need to use the right plugins/plugins. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/38669951/218196 .